# Field "id" should be an integer in latest task : Zapier

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

I want to publish my app live. When iI click on "Publish", I get some Validate Integration errors.

[Here](https://www.screencast.com/t/zZ4TKSpZ8UF) you can see the page. Under Activation Tasks, I am unable to understand what the field "Field "id" should be an integer in latest task (ID: *******)" means.

I have already passed "id" as an integer and "success" as string, but I'm still getting the error. I am totally unable to proceed further.

Can you please explain to me how to proceed, as I want to send live app live.

Comment: can you update your question to include a screenshot of the actual error you're getting? I don't see the one you mentioned.

Comment: Hello sir, I have solve the above mistake. can u please explain me this
https://www.screencast.com/t/dAA9AEpH
"There should be no more than 3 important triggers, you have 10"

Comment: see information here: https://platform.zapier.com/docs/integration-checks-reference#d020---too-many-important-triggerssearchesactions